# validate/echo checkboxes in php form

Tags: php, forms, validation, checkbox

First-timer working on a PHP form with checkboxes. These methods are all working on my other inputs, but I obviously don't understand how to process an array. I want to keep checkboxes checked upon refresh/submit, so user doesn't have to re-do, and I'm trying to validate all form values to prevent injection.

Here's the input:

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="project[]" id="project-type1" value="type1" <?php if ((isset($project)) && (in_array( 'type1', $project))) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?>/>Type 1</p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="project[]" id="project-type2" value="type2" <?php if ((isset($project)) && (in_array( "type2", $project))) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?>/>Type 2</p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="project[]" id="project-type3" value="type3" <?php if ((isset($project)) && (in_array( "type3", $project))) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?>/>Type 3</p>
  <p>
    <div class="error" id="error-project">
      <?php if (isset($err_project)) { echo $err_project; } ?>
      <?php if (isset($err_project2)) { echo $err_project2; } ?>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

Here, I'm attempting to trim, sanitize and echo the checkbox data:

```html
if (isset($_POST['project'])) { 
  $trimmed_project = array_map('trim', ($_POST['project'])); 
  $project = filter_var($trimmed_project, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); }
```

And here, I'm validating that only letters, spaces & commas are allowed to be submitted:

```html
if ( !(preg_match('/^([A-Za-z\ \,]+)$/', $project)) ) : $err_project2 = "
<p>Project Type value is invalid.</p>"; endif;
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: FYI- Code Snippet feature is only for HTML/JavaScript/CSS that you can run on this page... i.e. - not incomplete code examples and certainly not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to use PHP to keep the checkboxes checked on page reload; however, you can use jquery and cookies to remedy this. You can take the example code below and utilize it for your needs. Some browsers don't allow offline cookies, so if you are testing this offline use IE and it should work. That way you can play around with it and find out how it best works for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Persist checkboxes</title>
    <style>
    button{
      margin-top:8px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="option3">
    </div>

    <button>Check all</button>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>


    <script>
      function handleButtonClick(button){
        if ($(button).text().match("Check all")){
          $(":checkbox").prop("checked", true)
        } else {
          $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false)
        };
        updateButtonStatus();
      }
      function updateButtonStatus(){
        var allChecked = $(":checkbox").length === $(":checkbox:checked").length;
        $("button").text(allChecked? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
      }
      function updateCookie(){
        var elementValues = {};
        $(":checkbox").each(function(){
          elementValues[this.id] = this.checked;
        });
        elementValues["buttonText"] = $("button").text();
        $.cookie('elementValues', elementValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
      }
      function repopulateFormELements(){
        var elementValues = $.cookie('elementValues');
        if(elementValues){
          Object.keys(elementValues).forEach(function(element) {
            var checked = elementValues[element];
            $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
          });
          $("button").text(elementValues["buttonText"])
        }
      }
      $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
        updateButtonStatus();
        updateCookie();
      });
      $("button").on("click", function() {
        handleButtonClick(this);
        updateCookie();
      });
      $.cookie.json = true;
      repopulateFormELements();
    </script>
```

Comment: This works great - thank you! The only peculiar thing I'll add, for others who might be in my situation -- This form is in a WordPress site and I'm using the wp_enqueue_script function to register jQuery. Using that alone, this doesn't work; but if I include the path to the jQuery script right in the form itself, then it works. I'll have to look into whether WP enqueued scripts have issues with external/included files.

Thanks again - much appreciated. It would have taken me forever to stumble upon that solution, myself.